# How do I hide the Unity Launcher when Clementine is running?

Tags: unity, launcher, ccsm, clementine, autohide

Everytime I start Clementine, my Unity launcher will stop hiding and will always remain on the foreground. I have tried setting "Hide Launcher" to "Dodge Windows", "Dodge Active Window", and to "Autohide", but it still doesn't hide. Now I am forced to use the "Never" setting, because otherwise I can't use a part of my screen.

Can anyone tell me how I can run clementine and hide the Launcher at the same time? I really like clementine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround: select a track in the library pane in Clementine, then drag it towards the left side of the screen, 'pushing' the launcher away. The launcher should disappear, and might behave ok for a little while longer. The problem sometimes is that after this trick, it is difficult to get the launcher to appear long enough when you really want it. So the workaround for the workaround is: play around with the launcher until it works. (For instance, get into another app like Firefox, select and drag text to the Ubuntu logo in the top left corner.)

I think the bug in Clementine happens when you drag a track to the playlist, so try double-clicking the track instead. (In fact, I get the same bug in several other apps when I try to drag and drop files or text).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem too. And then I did this: press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open desktop switching view, choose one of the empty desktop (not the current). Then your launcher would hide right away. Go back to your previous desktop, the same way by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
It worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's some kind of bug the launcher has with many programs. When you drag-and-drop something is Clementine or Kdenlive, the launcher won't hide anymore until you close the program. Best solution I can think of is just avoid using drag-and-drop :p So just double-click in stead of drag-and-dropping.